# Laravel getting javascript file as locale

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, localization, datetimepicker

I am using Datapicker in Laravel project. I also implemented localalization there. The problem is Laravel is getting `pikaday.js` file as locale at first session. However, when I set locale manually as `/en` everything works fine untill the end of the session. How can I deal with this problem?

`dd(\app()->getLocale());` is showing this:

[image: locale at dd]

Here is the middleware for localization:

[image: Localization middleware]

This is the way of how I am importing js files for Datepicker.

[image: js files]

Answer (score 1):

You can add local under script
After below var can be used in the javascript file.

```
<script>
var locale = '{{ config('app.locale') }}';
console.log(locale);
</scripe>
```